# Quiz dinamicos, eliminar pregunta y pasar a la siguiente JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen dia estoy practicando algo de JavaScript y quería hacer un tipo de examen donde al responder una pregunta me arrojara la siguiente pregunta, y así sucesivamente 5 veces como es el siguiente ejercicio https://codepen.io/gcarino/pen/LDgtn?editors=1010, pero tengo un problema en el cual me que he quedado un poco estancado. Es que no es como hacer para que luego de responder la primera pregunta y me arroje la siguiente. Ya he probado preguntando en caso de que al responder la primera pregunta y borrar los elementos pregunte que el contenedor no tenga hijos y agregue la siguiente, creando un arregle de objetos para los parámetros de las preguntas para recorrer y trate de buscar un método en el cual hasta que se ejecute X función no ejecute la siguiente la cual es imprimir la nueva pregunta luego de borrar la anterior. Se que en el ejemplo esta la solución usada pero realmente sobre JQuery se poco o nada no entiendo muy bien la solución. ¿cómo podría responder una pregunta, eliminarla el HTML de los elementos de esa pregunta y pasar a la siguiente?.

```js
// los elementos que obtenemos del HTML
const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz")
const startList = document.getElementById("startList")
const buttonSend = document.getElementById("button-send")

// mostramos en cual pregunta estamos y cual es
function titleAndQuestion(qN, textQ) {
  let questionNumber = document.createElement("LI")
  questionNumber.innerHTML = `<h2 id='number-quest'>Question ${qN}:</h2>`
  startList.appendChild(questionNumber)
  // cual es la pregunta que esperamos que resuelva
  let theQuestion = document.createElement("LI")
  theQuestion.innerHTML = `<h3 id='the-question'>What is ${textQ}?</h3>`
  startList.appendChild(theQuestion)
}


//funcion que almacena y muestra las opciones de respuesta
function valuesOptions(a, b, c, d, e) { //la respuesta podria ser un parametro
  let valuesA = [a, b, c, d, e]
  let documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let elementLi = document.createElement("LI")
    elementLi.innerHTML = `<input type='radio' id='elemento-${i + 1}' name='answer'><label for='elemento-${i + 1}'>${valuesA[i]}</label><br>`;
    elementLi.classList.add("elemento-radio")
    documentFragment.appendChild(elementLi)
  }
  startList.appendChild(documentFragment)

}

// está es la respuesta, esta ubicada en el elemento 3
function clickDeleteItems() {
  let itemClassRadio = document.getElementsByClassName("elemento-radio")

  buttonSend.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let radioClicked = 0; //en esta variable sabremos si se selecciono alguna opcion
    for (let inspector = 0; inspector < itemClassRadio.length; inspector++) {
      if (itemClassRadio[inspector].childNodes[0].checked == true) {
        radioClicked = 1;
        //luego de elegir una opcion eliminaremos la pregunta anterior para poner una nueva
        let numberChilds = startList.childNodes.length; //una variable temporal que almacene la cantidad de hijos
        for (let iterator = 0; iterator < numberChilds; iterator++) {
          if (startList.hasChildNodes()) {
            startList.removeChild(startList.childNodes[0])
          }
        }
      } else {}
    }
    if (radioClicked == 0) alert("Es necesario que marques una respuesta para continuar")

  })
}

titleAndQuestion(2, "3*6")
valuesOptions(3, 6, 9, 12, 18)
clickDeleteItems()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Examen interactivo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Learning Js Properly: Project #1 - Dynamic Quiz</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="quiz">
      <ul id="startList"></ul>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Envie su respuesta" id="button-send">
    <!-- <input type="button" value="elimine lo anterior" id="erase-elements"> -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No tienes un arreglo de preguntas/respuestas, no hay forma de avanzar a "la siguiente" porque simplemente no existe. No puedo ver el ejemplo de _Codepen_, parece que no le gusta _Firefox_ o mi IP. Por cierto, en tu código no hay _jQuery_, solo Javascript puro.

Comment: El ejemplo del arreglo lo di porqué en algun momento me pidieron que explicara las formas que habia intentado(no funciono y omiti eesa parte). debe ser entonces por la IP, yo uso Firefox como navegador principal. el codigo JQuery al que me refiero es al usado en el ejemplo en CodePen.

Comment: Entonces, lo ideal es que coloques el código con arreglos que intentaste y no funcionó, con un ejemplo así sería más fácil tratar de ayudar.